# misexec trying to update app that launched msiexec?

Tags: windows-installer

We have an updating app for our product that checks a specific network location for a new MSI, and if found, installs it. The MSI always contains a replacement for the update app as well.

When the MSI runs the update app screen disappears after 3 seconds but you can see in task manager that it is still running for another 20 seconds or so.

We think that the installer tries to kill anything that is using files in the MSI including the update app and this causes the update app screen to disappear. I cannot prove this but if I run the update app from somewhere else and fool it into thinking it is running from the product folder, not only does the screen stay but the installation completes significantly faster.

Lots of products have updaters and I presume they run a copy of the update app from a temporary location to avoid this problem.

The issue we will face with this is that a lot of our clients have highly constrained environments and there is no certainty that we can copy or run an EXE from another location.

I had expected to find some some switches on MSIEXEC to deal with this very issue, but I see none.

Packaging the update app separately is one option, is there anything else I could try first?

Comment: You should be able to copy the launcher to a temp folder - it's difficult to believe your app cannot use a temp folder. There may be an elevation issue maybe, the updater may need an elevation manifest? Your app may need Restart Manager integration to avoid the issue otherwise, just a guess. You should also do the install of the update creating a verbose log to see what may be going on.

Comment: The install does not appear to fail, the updater itself has not been updated in years so I don't know whether it is actually being replaced or not. I will look at elevation manifest, new to me. Thanks.